# Change browser background colour

Tags: javascript, background

Hope this is ok. Asked a similar question the other day but I wasn't as clear as I could have been so trying again!

I am trying to produce an elearning course where the browser background colour changes as the user moves through it. So far I can set the background to a solid colour eg:

```
document.body.style.background = "#7BC4CC";
```

If I then use the same code as above but replace the colour with a new colour, when the new JS is executed the colour changes but is very abrupt. I would like a short fade transition between the two

So, JS would start on one background colour, short fade, into new colour. Pretty sure it has to be JS due to limitations with the elearning software I am using.

thanks in advance!

Comment: what elearning software are you using? can you use external libraries like jquery?

Comment: Articulate Storyline.

It allows me to place a trigger to 'Execute Javascript' when something happens, like the page loads or a user clicks a button I've built.

Comment: https://articulate.com/support/article/javascript-best-practices-and-examples

This tells you a little more about the do's and dont's

Apologies I am not too familiar with JS (trying to learn!) so not sure about jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could set the transition property along with the background color to enable a smooth transition.

```js
document.body.style.background = "#7BC4CC";

document.addEventListener('click', () => transitionTo('#edaf44'));


function transitionTo(color){
   document.body.style.transition = 'background-color 300ms';
   document.body.style.background = color;
}
```

```html
<button>transition to other color</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked it out in the end so this was useful!

I think the elearning software I use basically replaces the button click part of your code and replaces it with an inbuilt trigger, so I dropped that, but apart from that the transition time etc worked well. Thanks!